# Java Swing Calling Methods Outside an ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to call a method outside of an actionlistener inside my Swing class. I am getting this error, "Illegal modifier for parameter generate; only final is permitted"

Please help, and let me know if I need to provide more information.

```
JButton btnAddGrade = new JButton("Add Grade");
btnAddGrade.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        generate();

    }           
});
btnAddGrade.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
btnAddGrade.setBounds(10, 54, 168, 28);
contentPane.add(btnAddGrade);

private void generate() { 
     //do something here
}
```

Comment: On which line of your code do you get this compiler error?

Comment: Your problem appears to be that you are trying to directly nest one method inside of another method or constructor, something that is not allowed in Java. Get generate outside of whatever method or constructor that it is held in.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an anonymous class from the `ActionListener` interface, so it will be treated like a class. And there is no declared method called "`generate()`" in your `ActionListener`.

Change the generate method's access modifier to public. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your generate method appears to be directly nested within another method or constructor, something not allowed in Java, and so the solution is to remove the method from this location and place it inside the class proper.

Another side issue is your use of `setBounds` which implies that you are using null layouts. While this is not causing your error, it will hurt you in the long run, and you will want to instead favor the use of layout managers and nested JPanels.

Comment: My method is in a frame creation constructor, if I move it outside of the constructor I will not be able to call upon my frames/panels/lists. How would I do this?

Comment: @JohnA: make them instance fields perhaps, but regardless, the generate method absolutely cannot stay within the constructor, period. Hard to say based on the small snippet of code posted. Please consider improving your question and posting a valid [mcve].